# My script for sorting files according to extension is failing

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I am recovering files from a broken disk but it's sorting them randomly in folders named dir1, dir2,...

I am trying to create a script that sorts them in folders according  their extension

The problem is that there are some files with no extension and the script is creating a folder for each of these files when it should be ignoring them.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

BASEPATH=/media/potato/toshiba/WD320
SOURCEPATH=$BASEPATH/recovered/*
DESTINATIONPATH=$BASEPATH/sorted
DELIMITER="."

function iterateFolder {
    for filename in $1; do
            #checks if file is actually a folder
            #if it is a folder call this function again
            if [ -d $filename ] ;
            then
                    echo "iterating folder $filename"
                    iterateFolder "$filename/*"
            else            
                    #checks if the name of the file has extension ( actually it checks if there is "." in the name of the file)
                    #if it doesn't, ignore the file

                    if [ -z "${filename##*$DELIMITER*}" ] ;
                    then
                            fileExtension="${filename##*.}"
                            #checks if already exists a folder in the destination folder with the name of the extension
                            if [ ! -d "$DESTINATIONPATH/$fileExtension" ] ;
                            then
                                    newDir="$DESTINATIONPATH/$fileExtension"
                                    echo "creating folder $newDir"
                                    mkdir -p $newDir
                            fi
                    fi
            fi
    done
}
iterafteFolder "$SOURCEPATH"
```

Comment: Won't help much, but my standard practice is that scripts MUST support `--debug`, `--verbose`, `--help` and `--nooperation` switches. I use a template to make this easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in the line `if [ -z "${filename##*$DELIMITER*}" ] ;`.  The `##` operator has to make a complete match to remove anything from the string; therefore, if the filename doesn't have a `.` in it, it will be unmodified by `##`, thus causing the `if` condition to succeed. We can test this in a shell:

```
$ foo=bar
$ if [ -z "${foo##*.*}" ]; then echo 'Yes'; fi
Yes
$
```

The more traditional way to do this would be to use `[[` and a `=~` qualifier to check against a regex. For example:

```
$ if [[ $foo =~ *.* ]]; then echo 'Yes'; else echo 'No'; fi
No
$
```

[You can learn more about `[[` here.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) The gist of it is that `[[` is more powerful and flexible at the cost of being a system binary and not a shell builtin, thus incurring a theoretical performance penalty due to starting up a new process. The penalty is pretty much negligible so you shouldn't worry about it.